# In NEXTJs application the Layout I defined in layout.tsx is not working properly. Would you guys find what to do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, web-applications

// This is my layout.tsx, in this file I made a div and gave a style of container which will apply in all of my components in a container. After rendering my components The is The text in h1 tag is not shown in the container but the moment, I inspect the browser text shows in the container how is this happening? How can I fix it?

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className} suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        <div className="container mx-auto font-sans">{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

// This is the code of my page.tsx

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { NextPage } from "next";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Jaydeep's Blog</title>
      </Head>
      
      <main>
        <h1 className="text-primary-dark text-3xl">Hello Next Js</h1>
      </main>
      
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

//Here I am attaching the screenshots of my browser without inspecting and after inspecting.
[image]
// after inspecting:
[image]